# Android PJSIP ack timeout

Tags: android, sip, pjsip

When I try to make an outbound call , the destination won't send ack for Invite request. and after 30 seconds (Timeout) the call dropped.
How I can change the ACK timeout to be infinity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACK timeout is Timer H(64*T1). So you can make it infinity by changing T1 value. But it's so risky.

Comment: Where I can change it?

Comment: @mFarouk where can I change this ACK timeout value?